# Please help me out with this Python error - 'invalid syntax'

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression

#### Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
house_price = [245, 312, 279, 308, 199, 219, 405, 324, 319, 255]
size = [1400, 1600, 1700, 1875, 1100, 1550, 2350, 2450, 1425, 1700]
size2 = np.array(size).reshape((-1, 1))
#fitting into the model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(size2, house_price)
print("Coefficients: \n", regr.coef_)
print("intercept: \n", regr.intercept_)
#############################
#formula obtained for the trained model
def graph(formula, x_range):
   x = np.array(x_range)
   y = eval(formula)
   plt.plot(x, y)
#plotting the prediction line 
graph('regr.coef_*x + regr.intercept_', range(1000, 2700))
print(regr.score(size2, house_price))
plt.scatter (size,house_price, color='black')
plt.ylabel('house price')
plt.xlabel('size of house')
plt.show()
```

#### Error

> ```
> **Error Line:print regr.predict([2000])**
> Error: File "<ipython-input-4-9afa91ca7f9e>", line 1
>     print regr.predict([2000])
>              ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess your problem is because of your print line. use print as a function:

Comment: It ran fine for me, just copy pasted your code.

Comment: pasted the outcome as an answer, do let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: @Toros91 I guess it is because he is using python 3.6

Comment: yeah very good chance, that is the reason why i tried mentioning my python version too. lets see.

Comment: Agreed, he needs brackets for the print. But, there is a much more nefarious problem in his way of using predict.

Comment: I was surprised this question got into HNQ with such generic title and code dump...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Since you are new, I will point out that pure coding questions will get more visibility and *might* get better answers on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). But, then as here, always 1) post code 2) say what it is supposed to do 3) describe the problem. the more information that you give, the more that you help others to help you (thsi question is well asked; I am just pointing out some guideline for all)

Comment: Sure. this s the 1st time i have posted a question.. so didn't know the procedure to do it

Comment: @Toros91 can you tell me for which version of python did this run well?

Comment: I've un-deleted the answer have a look, was using Python 2.7. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3):

In your current line

```
print regr.predict([2000])
```

This will not work. The first error is the lack of brackets around the contents of your print statement which is required in Python 3. Change this first to

```
print(regr.predict([2000]))
```

However, you will see that this does not work either. I suspect you are attempting to evaluate the price for a new $size = 2000$. You will need to reshape the input to your regression for this to work.

```
new_size = np.array([2000]).reshape((-1, 1))
print(regr.predict(new_size))
```

> [ 317.78380528]

Comment: +1 I din't know about that bracket thing for python version above 3, nice will remember.